# Typescript use a module import as an interface

Tags: typescript

I have a module that defines a number of functions:

```
export function setNodeCount(count: i32): void {
  nodeCount = count;
}

export function getNodeCount(): i32 {
  return nodeCount;
}
```

Which I am then importing into another typescript file as follows:

```
import * as force from '../force';
```

I'd like to be able to mock / interchange `force` with a variable that is in global scope.

In order to achieve that I am having to define an interface for the functions exported by this module:

```
interface Force {
  setNodeCount: (number) => void;
  getNodeCount: () => number;
}
```

Then implement this via the imported module, or the global:

```
const importImpl: Force = {
  setNodeCount: force.setNodeCount,
  getNodeCount: force.getNodeCount
}

const globalImpl: Force = {
  getNodeCount: globalObject.getNodeCount,
  setNodeCount: globalObject.setNodeCount
};
```

At runtime I can then choose between these two implementations.

Is there an easier way to determine the interface for an imported module and dyanmically replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Since TypeScript uses structural typings, it is not necessary to define an explicit interface (`Force`) and use it as the type of `importImpl` and `globalImpl`. Both already have the same inferred interface.

If you need this type elsewhere in your code, I think that we can "capture" it this way: `type Force = typeof force;`.